# Doctrine create sql from entities but only for un-migrated changes?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using the console command `doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql` to generate the SQL for a migration file.

I'm repeatedly running it as I'm making small changes to the entities during development (Entity first design, rather than SQL first) to keep my dev db schema up to date.

However that is generating the full schema and not just the entities that have been modified. Is there a way of only generated the SQL for the modified entities?

No luck with google search or `doctrine:schema:create --help`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `doctrine/migrations-bundle`. With each change of your entities you can run:

`bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`: This will show all the edits you made to your entities

Then run the following to update your database:

`bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Comment: Strongly approve this answer. 
I advise anyone looking to update database with doctrine to never use something else than doctrine migration. 
In production environment its mandatory to prevent "breaking everything" and getting fired ahahah